# How to find path of image on Android?

Tags: android, path

Assuming my image is image_android.jpeg is at the root of my sdcard folder, how can I access to it ?

I would like to use it in this function :

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("PATH ??/image_android.jpeg");
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File("/image_android.jpeg").getPath());`

Comment: Thank you, How can I make sure that it actually loads it ? Because I use the image in a way that I don't really have knowledge about if it's load or not

Comment: I looked at the log and got E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /image_android.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) :/

Comment: Of course. That was wrong code. But you are out of luck. You cannot determine the removable media path in an Android device reliable or at all. So the user has to find out -with a file explorer app- the path of the microSD card. And then type it in so you can use it later. Or provide/use a file picker so the user can pick the file.